# How can I destroy an object after X seconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is in that way it will create more and more objects if automatic or if using the mouse.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScifiEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnEffect;
    public bool automaticFire = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (automaticFire == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                GameObject effect = Instantiate(spawnEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, spawnEffect.transform.forward)) as GameObject;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject effect = Instantiate(spawnEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, spawnEffect.transform.forward)) as GameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

If I add :

```
Destroy(effect);
```

Either in the mouse or if automatic the gameobject will be destroy at once and the effect will not happen. I could use a coroutine but then I will have to call the StartCoroutine inside the Update either if automatic or not and it will start many coroutines.

Comment: @Iggy This is working good. Just for the knowledge, what is the different between Destroy with time and object pooling ? Why not using object pooling in this case ? Destroying with time looks like object pooling.

Answer (score 2):

[`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) takes an optional second parameter

> **t** The optional amount of time to delay before destroying the object.

So you can e.g. simply do

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    GameObject effect = Instantiate(spawnEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, spawnEffect.transform.forward)) as GameObject;

    Destroy(effect, 3.5f);
}
```

To destroy the `effect` object after `3.5` seconds

---

Note however that you probably should **not** `Instantiate` an object **every frame** in your `else` case. Rather you could define a certain interval like e.g.

```
// adjust in the Inspector
public float maxSpawnPerSecond = 2f;

...

private float timer;

void Update()
{
    if (!automaticFire)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Spawn();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(maxSpawnPerSecond > 0)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;

            if(timer <= 0)
            {
                Spawn();

                timer = 1 / maxSpawnPerSecond;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Spawn()
{
    GameObject effect = Instantiate(spawnEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, spawnEffect.transform.forward)) as GameObject;

    Destroy(effect, 3.5f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no downsides to starting a bunch of coroutines other than regular coding issues like infinite loops.

Also coroutines has exactly what you need with a method called **WaitForSeconds()** that only works in coroutines. *As far as I know*

```
void Update()
{
    if(true) // Change if statement so you don't create an infinite loop and crash your program
    {
        StartCoroutine("SpecialEffects");
    }
}

IEnumerator SpecialEffects()
{
    // Special Effects
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    // Code that destroys something
}
```

Comment: What is the different between Destroy with time and object pooling ? Why not using object pooling in this case ? Destroying with time looks like object pooling. So we have Destroy(object,time) we have Coroutine and we have object pooling. I must say the Destroy with time is working very nice.  but in the end my main goal is to use this for a minigun that rotate nonsotp and I want to shoot bullets out of it maybe I should make another question for the shooting.

Comment: A "Coroutine" is basically just a normal method while "Object Pooling" is reusing the same limited amount of variables. (Example: I can't use more than 2 variables so I need to clear a variable to make a new variable)

Comment: Well there is a downside in Coroutines if you start a lot of them ofcourse ... they cause overhead since each of them has to be called `MoveNext` on every frame so if like you did you start one Coroutine every frame waiting for e.g. 3 seconds you get up to `180` parallel routines .. all actually just doing nothing then wait ...

Comment: @derHugo You're right, but just to clarify. My answer of "SpecialEffect()" is suppose to be more of a guideline than an exact solution. I tried to convey that through my comment of "Code that destroys something". I meant it as "Put whatever code you want/need after you did the waiting". Although, your answer is much more clear, I completely forgot about Destroy()'s second parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `Thread.Sleep(miliseconds);` to wait before it happens. You could also make a Task which sleeps for a while and then does the delete, make sure to `await` it.

Comment: you definitely do **NOT** want to make the main UI thread `sleep` in a frame based application!